# Error loading class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

**is the console log error **

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginLogDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.spring.dao.LoginLogDao.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

below is my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.service" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.196.5:3307/apu" 
    p:username="dev"
    p:password="password" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethod" expression="execution(* com.spring.service..*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceMethod" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

below is my test file

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
    import com.spring.model.User;
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/applicationContext.xml"})
    public class TestUserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Test
    public void hasMatchUser() {
        boolean b1=userService.hasMatchUser("admin", "123456");
        boolean b2=userService.hasMatchUser("admin", "11111");
        assertTrue(b1);
        assertTrue(!b2);
    }

    @Test
    public void findUserByName(){
        User user = userService.findUserByUserName("admin");
        assertEquals(user.getUserName(),"admin");
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix the problem,who can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookes like you have to change the jar file for `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` .It is creating problem

```
UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file Related cause:     
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class 
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
```

Comment: i have add commons-dbcp-1.4.jar and commons-pool-1.6.jar but the problem isn't solved

Comment: Thanks i have solve the problem change the commons-dbcp-1.4.jar to commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

The bad version number error is shown because you might have compiled your java file to a class file with one version and are trying to run it with an earlier version. Check if there is no version conflicts in development and other environments.